# python3: math.cos() returns wrong value

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I  needed to calculate with `math.cos` and `math.sin` this strange error occured:

```
>>> from math import *
>>> cos(radians(90))  # here is my problem
6.123233995736766e-17
>>> cos(90)  # not a surprise
-0.4480736161291701
```

but my calculator (and I) says, that (in `deg`-mode) `cos(90) = 0`.

As the result is pretty close to 0, is it just a floatingpoint error, or is there a serious problem?

Comment: 6e-17 is zero as far as the computer is concerned. cos(90) is cosine of 90 radians, and not of 90 degrees. The purpose of the `radians()` function is to trranslate from degrees to radians! (It really should have been called deg2rad, or something similar, imho.)

Comment: _"or is there a serious problem?"_ How should we know whether it's serious? If you're writing a circle drawing algorithm, the 10e-17 difference is insignificant. If you're writing a control system for the space shuttle, it might mean you miss Mars by a thousand miles.

Comment: @Kevin I should have asked 'does math.cos behave not like this on your machine'.

Comment: Sorry to poke fun at your question ;-) math.cos gives the same result on my machine.

Comment: @DovGrobgeld I do know that cos(90) is of the radians 90. I just wanted to clarify, that I tested this, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to floats.

If anyone tells you that 6e-17 is not 0 then ignore them. Some calculators will actually round for you.

You can use the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) to make it show 0. But by no means that answer is wrong

Not that I disagree with @Kevin comment about Mars, but the math functions are only estimation they don't use the full extent of [Taylor's Series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) in this case. I'm sure, and I hope NASA implements them differently (different algorithm is possible) than what you see in a basic calculator/computer.

Comment: yes I guessed it was the floatingpoint error, but I wanted to be sure about it. thx